# remove alertbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am Using the below js function

```
function view_city(val) {
    var val = document.getElementById("city").value;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var availableTags1 = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: "res.php?key=" + val,
            success: function(result1) {
                var result1 = result1;
                var availableTags1 = result1.split("|");

                $("#city").autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags1
                });
            }
        });
        alert(availableTags1);
    });
```

Here I didn't require the alert box, If i removed the alert box the function will not work properly, Please Help me What the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a race condition somewhere, Alertboxes will lock the thread, giving the ajax call the time to complete as it is processed out side your main thread. I'd look to see if you are calling for data anywhere outside your ajax call back, or depending on that data before its actually available to the call back.

It may be outside the code you posted.

Also some of this code looks cyclical, why would you expecta value in city other than "" on page load when you make your ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `alert(availableTags1);` by `return;`.